# What does while(p) mean? (p is a pointer to the first element of a C style string)

Tags: c++, pointers, character

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    char* c = "Hello World!";
    char* p = c;
    while (p && *p) {
        std::cout << *p << std::endl;
        ++p;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Look at the above.

It is a short code example in an exercise of C++.

I can understand **while(*p)** which means **loop until the last character('\0') is reached**.

But I can't understand **while(p)**.

What does while(p) mean? (p is a pointer to the first element of a C style string)

Comment: What does every C-string end with? (answer a *nul-character*, e.g. `'\0'` that has the decimal value `0`). So when you test `while (p && *p)`, you first test `p != NULL` and then `*p != '\0'`. This allows you to validate that the original pointer isn't `NULL` to begin with and then iterate over each character until the current character is the *nul-character* marking the end of the string, either of which will terminate the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while (p)` part makes sure that the value of `p` is nonzero, and the `while (*p)` checks to make sure that the dereferenced value of `p` is nonzero.

Therefore, if the string itself (the pointer to it) `p` is nonzero, and it's current character `*p` is not `'\0'`, the `while` loop block will execute.

Comment: Is it possible that the string itself (the pointer to it) p is  zero ?  I guess the while(p) may not make any sense.

Comment: In this case, with your code, no. It is safe to remove it from the ‘while’ statement.

Comment: You mean while(p) may have its practical use in some other scenarios, right ?

Comment: Well, slightly. Even if it is a nonzero value in other scenarios, the string may point to some memory which is either restricted, inaccessible, or has been released. Only if you cannot check the original pointer, and you must create a new pointer to check if it’s zero, it’s necessarily not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the pointer itselfs is not null - which may be of use if used in a function and p is an argument.

In this example it is useless since p can never be null since.